# Which URLs will the forge viewer access?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want a list of URLs that the forge viewer(v7) may access.
Forge viewer running environment is restricted outbound access with URL(and port) whitelist.

e.g.) fonts.autodesk.com:440, developer.api.autodesk.com:80

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, all the Forge Viewer assets (incl. fonts) are coming from https://developer.api.autodesk.com only.

If you're seeing other domains being accessed, those might be accessed by the application itself, not by Forge Viewer.